# Whats wrong with my Apex Class? It throws ERROR Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, class

In Execute Anonymous it works fine
Code:

```
List<Room__c> c=[SELECT id,Name,Customer__c FROM Room__c];
System.debug(c);
```

But in Apex Class it throws an error as

> Didn't understand relationship 'Customer' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Code:

```java
public with sharing class RoomController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Room__c> getAllRooms() {
        List<Room__c> c=[SELECT id,Name,Customer.Name FROM Room__c];
        return  c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the parent object field in SOQL you should use __r . Can you change you query as below and try.

```
SELECT id,Name,Customer__r.Name FROM Room__c
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicely the error message tells you what's wrong. As per the other answer you need to change `Customer__c` custom field name to `Customer__r` in order to then access a field from that related object, as in `Customer__r.Name`.

Only standard Salesforce object and field names omit the `__c` suffix and do not require an `__r`. For example, a `Contact` has a related `Account` record that is referenced in the `AccountId` lookup field. To query a field from the related Account when querying the Contact you would use the relationship name of `Account`, as in `Account.Name`.

Your example is a custom object, so all field names (other than the standard fields generated on it automatically, such as Id and Name etc.) have the `__c` suffix. You then always replace this with `__r` to query fields from that related record too.